# Mail sent error in magento2

Tags: magento2.3, email

When i try to send an email throughgh Email your friend https://prnt.sc/olekdn i am getting this error
https://prnt.sc/olek0m
SMTP configurations are https://prnt.sc/olel1c.

Please help what can be the issue

Comment: Does the account with abs@abs.com exist? Have you tried to send the test email?

Comment: I have put proper account address, just for screen shot i added abs@abs.com. when i do test email, the email properly gets sent. even if i create an account, account confirmation link goes to an email, no issues there. only on email a friend  i am getting this issue

Comment: Have you checked the email a friend controller from where email is triggered, any error logs seen

Comment: I figured out the problem. In email a friend the sent to address should be the one i set in SMTP config i.e abs@abs.com, and not to be the user's email address, but this is wrong. i want to send it with user's email address.

Answer (score 0):

This could bring light to your issue

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/69426f64-717d-47e0-aa1b-700903ee83cc/520-storedrv-error?forum=exchangesvrsecuremessaginglegacy

Can you try checking on your

```
Stores > Configuration > General > Contacts > Email Sender
```

SendAsDeniedException does relate to the email sender being not authorized to use the domain server.

Comment: This is set to General contact